# Javascript manipulating / transforming JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I currently have a react component that accepts data that looks like the following. This is for, as you've probably guessed. A datatable.

```
const data = {
        rows: [
            {row: [
                {cell:'abc2'},
                {cell:'abc2'},
                {cell:'abc2'}, 
                {cell:'abc2'}, 

            ]},
            {row: [
                {cell:'abc'},
                {cell:'abc'},
                {cell:'abc'}, 
                {cell:'abc'}, 

            ]},
        ]
    }
```

Now. I want to somehow build a function that can transform data in any form into that pattern. For example. Given the following:

```
   {  
      "id":"35078",
      "employee_name":"hspl200",
      "employee_salary":"0",
      "employee_age":"0",
      "profile_image":""
   }
```

I'd like to tranform that into object a cell based row which would become:

```
   {row: [ 
      {cell:"35078"},
      {cell:"hspl200"},
      {cell:"0"},
      {cell:"0"},
      {cell:""}
   ]},
```

and so on.  I could write something custom for every time I need data for the datatable in this format, but ultimately a better solution probably exists to shape / transform json object from one pattern to another.

What libraries / techniques etc. should I be investigating in order to achieve this in a more reusable way?

Comment: There's actually very little necessary to do that.  While some libraries could help, just starting with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) should get you a fair way toward your goal.

Comment: I have an opinion: Dont use libraries or meta functions like map() for these tasks.  Write a short, pure function, that uses Object.values() and youre done.

Comment: I have a contrary opinion.  ;-)  Don't use libraries, but definitely *do* use `map` for this.  It's much more explicit about what it's supposed to return.

Comment: What probably wasn't obvious from my question was the potential unreliable format of the input data structure and attempting to cater for that. I guess isArray and Object entries etc. could possibly do it just thought it seemed like it should be a solved problem already.

Comment: @Squiggs: I'm not sure what range of input structures you would want to support.  Really generic code would require substantial configuration to use properly.  If you have a list of objects like this, all structured exactly the same, it's easy to write a generic transformation.  But if the properties might be in different order, or if some might be missing altogether, this becomes harder.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - atm, I can control the JSON structure server side. But I'm trying to cater for the situation of consuming any API where the structure cannot be controlled just by passing keys to look out for in the json. Going to give a few different formats a bash for now and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a trivial way to turn an object into a row:

```js
const makeRow = (value) => ({
  row: Object.values(value).map(val => ({cell: val}))
})

const value = {"id":"35078","employee_name":"hspl200","employee_salary":"0","employee_age":"0","profile_image":""}

console.log(makeRow(value))
```

But if you don't really know your structure, you could write something like this to turn a collection of similar objects into (a slight variant of) that data style:

```js
const vals = [
  {"id":"35078","employee_name":"hspl200","employee_salary":"0","employee_age":"35","profile_image":"pic1.jsp"},
  {"id":"35079","employee_name":"hr4f302","employee_salary":"1","foobar":"baz","profile_image":"pic2.jpg"},
]

const makeTable = (values) => {
  // get the superset of all objects' property names.
  const headers = [...values.reduce(
    (s, v) => Object.keys(v).reduce((s, k) => s.add(k), s),
    new Set()
  )]
  return {
    data: {
      headers: headers.map(h => ({cell: h})),
      rows: values.map(
        value => ({
          row: headers.map(h => ({cell: value[h] || ''}))
        })
      )
    }
  }
}

console.log(makeTable(vals))
```

Note that although the keys of the objects overlap a great deal, they are not identical.  This uses an empty string to report the nil values, although you can just remove the `|| ''` to stop that.

Your suggested output seems to have an extra unnecessary level of nesting.  Perhaps that's the requirement for your datatable format, but if not, you could remove the nested `row` property by replacing the relevant lines with

```js
        value => (
          headers.map(h => ({cell: value[h] || ''}))
        )
```

(Also note that I have no idea if there is a separate node for headers like I showed here.  But if not, you could just concatenate that result and the rows into one array.)

Comment: Fantastic. This gives me a great place to start to build a solution from. You are correct on your headers assumption that there is some building of that required as well. I can also safely remove the additional layer of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

As having a generic solution to such a practical situation will still require a lot of configuration to accommodate specific requirements.

You can follow this kind of approach while dealing with this kind of data:

```
 var data=[{  
      "id":"35078",
      "employee_name":"hspl200",
      "employee_salary":"0",
      "employee_age":"0",
      "profile_image":""
   },{

      "id":"35078",
      "employee_name":"hspl200",
      "employee_salary":"0",
      "employee_age":"0",
      "profile_image":""
   }]

 const newData=data.map((item)=>{
   return {
     row:Object.values(item).map((val)=>{
       return {'cell':val}
     })
   }
 })
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Note that the `return` statements and block bodies for the arrow functions are more distracting here than helpful.  Compared to the function in the first snippet of my answer, this seems unnecessarily verbose.  Of course, *de gustibus non est disputandum.*